# Get .attr() of class and save it in var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a custom attribute that I want to read with jQuery, store the number in a `var` and use that var to calculate a new height for the element.

```js
var test;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myclass');
  test = $(this).attr('data-rows');
    alert(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass" data-rows="11" style="height: 200px;">
  <p>
    Some Content here
  </p>
</div>
```

But I get an undefined var.

Would be great if somebody could assist me here.
Thanks

Comment: `$('.myclass');` selects the element(s) and is immediately disposed because you are not referencing it.

Comment: You can do it with just `test = $('.myclass').data('rows');`

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark the correct answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Comment: @connexo it is, but Rakibul Islam didn't post any answer only a comment with the solution

Comment: And none of the other answers suits your needs and explains your problem properly?

Answer (score 2):

`$('.myclass');` selects the element(s) and is immediately disposed because you are not referencing it. You want to assign it to a variable, in my example `$test`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $test = $('.myclass');
  const test = $test.data('rows');
  console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass" data-rows="11" style="height: 200px;">
  <p>
    Some Content here
  </p>
</div>
```

It is common practice to prefix variable names with `$` when they store jQuery objects.

The same code in pure Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.myclass');
  const test = el.dataset.rows;
  console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<div class="myclass" data-rows="11" style="height: 200px;">
  <p>
    Some Content here
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're asking for the **jQuery** equivalent, but here (for additional reference) is the vanilla javascript (using `dataset`):

> I got a custom attribute that I want to read with jQuery, store the number in a var [...]

```
const myClassElement = document.querySelector('.myclass');
const test = myClassElement.dataset.rows;
```

> [...] and use that var to calculate a new height for the element.

```
myClassElement.style.setProperty('height', (test * 24) + 'px');
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset